# stop shiny app to refresh whole page automatic, when underline data base gets new data

Tags: r, shiny

I have shiny website, where I update data every 15 min, and then whole page is resets. I loose all work on website.

Do you know anyway to stop that refresh, and fix current state of website.

I am trying to find alternative of reactiveFileReader
Thanks

Comment: Read [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5977215), then include enough code in your question so that others can see what you're trying to do and offer a solution.

Comment: If I understand, your application currently refreshes any time a change is detected in `reactiveFileReader`, but you don't want it to refresh until you request a refresh? If that is correct, remove the `reactiveFileReader` and place an action button to refresh on demand.

Comment: You are spot on. We have rds extension file. However when I tried to read using readRDS. It is not working. Any ideas ?